# Trying to use Mysql to count frequency in this example php?

Tags: php, mysql

My example table is below. I have 4 apples, two rows between the first apple and the second apple, and one row between second apple and third apple, two rows between third apple and fourth apple. Is that possible to know how many rows between each apple and the next apple with Mysql.

```
id      fruit
1        berry
2        apple
3        bananan
4        berry
5        apple
6        berry
7        apple
8        berry
9        berry
10       apple
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will calculate the difference in ID between each apple and the next one.

```
SELECT a.id, MIN(b.id)-a.id AS diff
FROM yourTable AS a
JOIN yourTable AS b ON a.id < b.id
WHERE a.fruit = 'apple'
AND b.fruit = 'apple'
GROUP BY a.id
```

Note that if there are gaps in the ID sequence, this counts those missing IDs in the difference.

Comment: I am amazed.@Barmar you are sure genious

Comment: Note that this will not be very efficient if there are thousands of apples in the table, because it generates O(N^2) combinations.

Comment: This makes a rather grave assumption about your data however!

Comment: RE: Your note: Surely then this is next to useless in a real life situation where rows may get deleted

Comment: @RiggsFolly It's not really clear what the actual use case of this is.

Comment: Ok, so @conan Try this test case. 1) run query on above data. 2) delete the row with `banana` in it. 3) run the query again. Now check the results. If it is even **faintly possible** that you would ever delete a row form this table, you are going to have to get @Barmar to come up with another answer for you

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well, there's a basic principle here that can be extended to any use case.

Comment: @Strawberry I was not knocking the answer. I just thought that the OP should be made aware that there should be some proviso's before they _bet the farm_ on this as a perfect solution